# How to query for Master Records without any child records?

Tags: soql

I want to get a list of Opportunity (Standard Object) Records, which is the Master Object, which have no associated Quotes__c (Custom Object), which is the Child Object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making some assumptions about your data model here, but try this:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Quote__c)
```

Comment: Please mark it as an answer then ...